# Unable to shut down MySQL server

Tags: mysql, mac-os-x, shutdown

I have tried using the system preferences and then shutting down MySQL there, but to no avail. I also tried typing `killall -9` and `-11`. Both failed :(.

I also tried `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown`. The last thing I tried is in the following screenshot... it also did not work.

[image]

I am using yosemite, if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you can shutdown using

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld stop
```

I cannot add comments so requesting to post what do you see in error log when you do

```
mysqladmin shutdown
```

About kill commands please note that mysqld_safe is wrapper script which will start mysqld upon killing... so you should kill mysqld_safe first followed by mysqld. ( not a suggested way though).

Refer: [how to stop mysql on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100948/how-do-you-stop-mysql-on-a-mac-os-install)

Comment: typing '/etc/init.d/mysqld stop' yields No such file or directory

Comment: typing 'mysqladmin shutdown' yields shutdown failed; error: 'Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SHUTDOWN privilege(s) for this operation'

Comment: Use root user... `mysqladmin -uroot -p shutdown`

Comment: that command works with no errors. However, when I check '                             ps -Af | grep mysql', I still have processes running. Additionally, in my system preferences, the MySQL Server Status is still running. When I click Stop MySQL server, it stops, but then runs moments later. Thanks so much for helping me thusfar!

Comment: Post what do you see in error log!!

Comment: I meant you to post in mysql error log.